# How to avoid deprecation warning for components extending Ember.TextField with ember 1.10.0

Tags: ember.js

I have a component "InstantSearchTextField" that extendeds Ember.TextArea and I wanted to use it in hbs without getting the deprecation warning.

this works:
{{view "App.InstantSearchTextField"}}

but the problem is I get deprecation error. 
I cannot do {{view "instant-seach-text-field"}}, I also tried to create a helper but that didn't work too. Here is a jsbin : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/muzogakugi/1/

What is the proper way to do this to avoid the deprecation warning?
Thanks,
Dee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your component in your template as follows:

```
{{instant-seach-text-field}}
```

Comment: I feel so dumb - figured out the issue, I screwed the naming convention. I had to name the component as "App.InstantSearchTextFieldComponent" instead of "App.App.InstantSearchTextField". Thanks Oren.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Good luck :)